# Handle Jackson Unexpected Data Type Changes

Tags: json, jackson

I'm using jackson to deserialize external API. 
This API returns JSON Object for particular property when there is data available, But when there is no data available its returning empty JSON Array instead of returning null. Its inconsistent but I can't do anything cz this is an external API.

When there is Data:

```
buy: {data1: value1, data2: value2}
```

When there is no Data

```
buy: []
```

I define My Jackson mapping data class as follows

```
class Test {
    @JsonProperty("buy");
    Map<String, String> buyOrders;
}
```

When there is data it works fine and I can get deserialized data successfully, But when there is no data, I'm getting

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token
```

which is perfectly fine, 
But Is there any annotation to assign null when there is invalid data type? instead of throwing exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a [custom deserializer](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers) which would treat `[]` as a null value. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonCustomNullDeserializer {

    public static class Test {
        final public Map<String, String> buyOrders;

        @JsonCreator
        public Test(@JsonProperty("buy")
                    @JsonDeserialize(using = MyMapDeserializer.class) Map<String, String> buyOrders) {
            this.buyOrders = buyOrders;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Test{" +
                    "buyOrders=" + buyOrders +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    private static class MyMapDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Map<String, String>> {
        protected MyMapDeserializer() {
            super(Map.class);
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            if (jp.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.START_ARRAY && jp.nextToken() == JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
                return null;
            }
            return jp.readValueAs(new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {});
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"buy\":{\"xxx\":\"yyy\"}}", Test.class));
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"buy\":[]}", Test.class));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Test{buyOrders={xxx=yyy}}
Test{buyOrders=null}
```

Comment: Great, this is what i've been looking for, Nice answer with example code.