# Keep on JSON deserialized when some property is different

Tags: java, json, jackson2

I am having troubles when JSON is being deserialized using Jackson.
The problem is when the JSON is deserialized and whatever JSON property is changed by DEV, I still need to get it deserialized into an object.

Here is the part of variables in the object

```
@JsonProperty("accountingFiscalYear")
public String accountingFiscalYear;
@JsonProperty("amount")
public Float amount;
@JsonProperty("debitFlag")
public Boolean debitFlag;
```

and here is the JSON part

```
"accountingFiscalYear": "2017",
"amount": 1632.0000,
"debitFlag": true,
```

When it runs it is deserialized without any problems. But if there is any change in the JSON response it fails during the deserialization like:

For example if I change the debitFlag data type from Boolean to Integer

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of int out of VALUE_TRUE token

I know it is right, but I would like to continue with deserialization and simply ignore types that could not be deserialized and keep them null.
Thanks for hints.

Comment: If there is any change in the JSON, it means that your API changed also so you will need to update your object. Or try instead of boolean or Integer, try Object, see if it works

Comment: You should look into custom deserializer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843267/handle-jackson-unexpected-data-type-changes